# Egit eclipse: resolve conflict without commit all files

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, atlassian-sourcetree

When in a git repository there is a conflict, after marking as resolved the conflicted file, in eclipse I can't commit only that file, but yes in sourcetree.

Is there any way to commit only one file in egit when there is a conflict?

Thanks!

[image: egit]

[image: sourcetree]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. After resolving the conflict right click on the file go to `Team > Add to Index` , then right click on the included project go to `Team > Commit`.

Note that **ADD ONLY** those file to **GIT index** in which you are interested in commit next time. If accidentally you added more file then you can remove these file from GIT index by right clicking on the file and selecting `Team > Remove from Index`

Comment: I can't do Team > Commit because I can't deselect files (even removing from index). But yes in Git perspective > Git stagins tab > Commit. Thanks!

Comment: You are Welcome!. Install new version of EGit it has new features and bug fixes